# How to scale all contents of a DIV by a certain percentage?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to do a sort of zoom-in/zoom-out effect, by animating all the dimensions of the contents (text, images, divs, etc) of a div by a certain percentage.

How can I do this? Similar to this: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US/+/demo/

Comment: You can do that with the canvas in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

That website uses the Maps API with custom tiles. You can look at the Maps API and do the same. But it is not really zooming text, btw. The tiles are all divs and images. As you reach the end of the animation, new set of images are brought in to replace the old depending on the zoom level.

You can use jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to scale your elements. You can also use canvas like @Babak mentioned, but I don't know if you want to go that far, I need to know more of your requirements.